# Laravel strange issue with cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, laravel-4

I'm trying to hide an alert message when a cookie exisits.

So I have this code:

```
@foreach($alerts as $alert)
  @if(empty(Cookie::get('alert_'.$alert->id)))
    <!-- alert -->
    <div class="alert alert-{{ $alert->type }} text-center">
    <a href="#" onclick="createCookie('alert_{{ $alert->id }}','true','9999')" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    {{ $alert->message }}
    </div>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

But when the cookie has a value it is still being displayed.

When I use isset() in the code, I get an error connection reset.

I use javascript to generate the cookies;

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Check for cookie exists**

Try this:

You can also fetch cookies using ***request***

To retrieve the value of a cookie use the following syntax:

```
$value = $request->cookie('nameOfCookie');
```

If required add instance ***Illuminate\Http\Request***

You can check if a cookie exists as below

```
if (Request::hasCookie('alert_'.$alert->id)) 
{
    // Success code here
} else { 
    // Failure code here
}
```

You can also check likewise:

```
if(Cookie::get('alert_'.$alert->id) != null) { .. }
```

Useful docs: [hasCookie](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_hasCookie) Method.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I tried them all... Nothing works. Remind that I have a foreach looping before that, maybe that does the thing?

Comment: I found the issue, but I can't fix it. So I say, when cookie `alert_[id]` exists it needs to hide, but when it doen't, it needs to display the alerts. The problem is, he shows all the alerts. So now I need to solve this, but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you tried this:   if(!isset(Cookie::get('alert_'.$alert->id))) { // show } else { // hide }

Comment: Yes, isses blocks my connection as I already said in the question.

Comment: Are you able to see each cookie value in the foreach loop ? Is there any null values ? Try a strlen == 0 check ???

Comment: I have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451398/javascript-cookies-wont-display-div-when-not-set because this doesn't work.